# ckeditor and codesnippets plugin

Tags: html, css, ckeditor

I'm baffled! I built ckeditor 4.13 using the online builder, and included the codesnippet plugin. Now when I chose the plugin within the editor from the toolbar it allows me to add the code under which ever language I choose, but the syntax highlighting doesn't work for all languages. For example CSS is not highlighted. The background of the chosen theme is there, but no highlighting. SQL queries are fine as are some others, but not CSS or PHP it would seem!

Also, I'm editing in one place and then viewing the article on another place (pulling the article from a database). The styling is completely missing altogether when it's the article is viewed. I tried to find a CSS file which may contain the classes that had been attached to the snippets (such as language-php) but couldn't. I thought if I just linked to the CSS file in my header it would attach the styling...I was wrong!

Any ideas how I can tackle this issue please? Google has brought nothing so far.

Comment: Okay so I've gotten around the issue of tags disappearing by using the htmlspeacialchars() php function on the actual textarea content when I echo it out from the database. All syntax highlighting looks correct and so the editor is working fine. 

The 'viewer' is still not showing the syntax colours though. To try and be clear, I have an admin area for article editing, and also a viewing area for reading the article. The ckeditor helps me put the article together in the admin area and then this gets saved to the database.

Comment: Then in the viewing area the article is pulled from the database and displayed (on a different page to the editor). The problem is that now the syntax highligting is gone, because the page doesn't know ow to find it or even that it's supposed to know it exists I guess! How do I get the syntax highlighter to work on the viewing page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I've found the best way to deal with the syntax highlighting issue is to download prism. This will work with the classes produced by ckeditors codesnippet plugin and colour code the syntax according the theme you chose from Prism. Look at prismjs.com.